# Пинг нескольких адресов одновременно

Tags: c#, асинхронность, ping

Всем здравствуйте! Не судите строго, т.к. только начинаю в этом разбираться. Задача у меня следующая: имеется список ip-адресов в excel файле и их необходимо проверять на доступность. В принципе, то что у меня сейчас есть устраивает, но не совсем, т.к. если список очень большой, то уходит достаточно много времени на проверку доступности этих ip-адресов, потому что проверка идет последовательно, т.е. сначала один ip-проверили, потом второй, третий и т.д. Можно ли этот процесс как-то ускорить, допустим запустить несколько параллельных процессов на проверку доступности ip-адресов? Посмотрев Интернет (в том числе и здесь), я так понимаю, что можно использовать асинхронный метод, но я что-то делаю не так, поэтому у меня особо ничего не получается... Помогите, пожалуйста :)

```
private static async void Run()
    {
            string path;

            Console.Write("Введите путь, указав имя файла: ");
            path = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            int i;
            int j = 1;
            int N;

            Console.Write("Количество строк: ");
            N = Convert.ToInt32((Console.ReadLine()));


            StreamReader f = new StreamReader(path);
            Excel.Application ObjWorkExcel = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook = ObjWorkExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"" + path + "", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];

        for (j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
                {
                    string pinger = ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, j].Text;
                    if (ObjWorkSheet.Rows[i].Text == null)
                    {
                        i++;
                    }

                    Ping pingSender = new Ping();

                    string data = "aaaaaaa";
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    PingOptions options = new PingOptions(64, true);

                    try
                    {
                        PingReply reply = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(pinger);

                        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", reply.Address, reply.Status));
                            (ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Interior.ColorIndex = 4;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}  {1}", reply.Address, reply.Status));
                            (ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Interior.ColorIndex = 3;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        (ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Interior.ColorIndex = 6;
                    }
                }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("ЗАВЕРШЕНО");
        Console.ReadLine();
        ObjWorkExcel.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать nping из https://nmap.org/nping/

Comment: code review: предлагаю отрефакторить, чтобы не было все в одном методе. Разделить код который пингует, от кода который парсит и кода который устанавливает результат в эксель.
+ async void зло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Пинг на чистом async/await:**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace TestPing
{
    class Program
    {
        class PingResult
        {
            public IPAddress Ip { get; set; }
            public IPStatus Status { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ipList = new List<IPAddress>();
            //ipList.Add(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, 69}));
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                ipList.Add(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, (byte)i}));
            }

            while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
                var items = SimplePing(ipList, 3, 2000).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                foreach (var item in items) {
                    if (item.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Ip.ToString()}: {item.Status.ToString()}");
                    }
                }

                if (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
            }
        }

        static async Task<IEnumerable<PingResult>> SimplePing(List<IPAddress> ipList, int retryCount, int timeout)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            var tasksResult = new ConcurrentQueue<PingResult>();
            foreach (var ip in ipList) {
                await Task.Delay(20); // без этого не кторые адресса могут не отвечать
                tasks.Add(DoPing(ip, retryCount, timeout, tasksResult));
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

            var result = new List<PingResult>();
            while (tasksResult.TryDequeue(out PingResult pingResult)) {
                result.Add(pingResult);
            }

            return result;
        }

        static async Task DoPing(IPAddress ipAddress, int retryCount, int timeout, ConcurrentQueue<PingResult> resultQueue)
        {
            using (var ping = new Ping()) {
                while (retryCount > 0) {
                    retryCount--;
                    var result = await ping.SendPingAsync(ipAddress, timeout);
                    if (result.Status != IPStatus.Success) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    resultQueue.Enqueue(new PingResult() {
                        Ip = ipAddress,
                        Status = result.Status
                    });

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PS:**
У сетевых железок есть функция(не знаю как нызывается, буду признателен если кто подкажет), которая может рубить пакеты если их слишком много в один момент времени(наверно это анти DDOS какой то). Что бы это обходить, в коде есть `Task.Delay(20)`. 20 это не сакральное число, можно выбрать другое приемлемое.

Answer (score 1):

Если интересен именно эксель, то можно из него запускать сразу несколько командных строк с командой (cmd.exe)

```
ping myip >> result%n%.txt
```

Где n - порядковый номер. И проверять результат исполнения уже из txt файла. Можно через макрос экселя запускать одновременно по 20-100 ip адресов... (по идее число неограниченно, только ресурсами машины)

Еще вариант создание BATника, в котором идёт вызов ping через команду start, что-то вроде:

```
start ping 1й_ip >> 1.txt
start ping 2й_ip >> 2.txt
....
start ping 100й_ip >> 100.txt
```

Эти 100 команд запустятся параллельно.